# Google Search API - "No results" text

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api, google-search-api

Is anybody have an idea how can I change the "No results" to some other text...

I have this code:

```
function OnLoad() {
  // Create a custom search control that uses a CSE restricted to code.google.com
  var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('http://******');

  // Draw the control in content div
  customSearchControl.draw('ArticleGoogleSearchBox');

}
```

Any Ideas???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is option like .setNoResultsString(str)

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/js/cselement-reference#cse-el

Answer (score 1):

You can find the clear solution here from this URL https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/js/rendering. Read section "Example: Using data attributes for conditionals, iteration, and local variables" and apply if-else attributes to customize your search contents.